# My Category is not found although it is in the dataset

Tags: r, dataset

I read in the data as below and do some modifications:

```
data1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/airline-safety/airline-safety.csv")
packages<- c("tidyverse","data.table", "reshape2")
sapply(packages, require, character.only=T)
data1<- data1 %>% gather(Category, Number, incidents_85_99:fatalities_00_14, factor_key=TRUE)
```

the head of original data is as below:

```
                airline avail_seat_km_per_week        Category Number
1            Aer Lingus              320906734 incidents_85_99      2
2             Aeroflot*             1197672318 incidents_85_99     76
3 Aerolineas Argentinas              385803648 incidents_85_99      6
4           Aeromexico*              596871813 incidents_85_99      3
5            Air Canada             1865253802 incidents_85_99      2
6            Air France             3004002661 incidents_85_99     14
```

but when I call this function:

```
data1[Category=="incidents_85_99"]
```

it shows:
Error in `[.data.frame`(data1, Character == "incidents_85_99") :
object 'Character' not found

Why I have this problem? Appreciate any help!!

Comment: A few things - `Character` is not a column name in `data1` (`Category` is). Also, you'll need to reference your data frame with the column name `data1[data1$Category == "incidents_85_99",]`...and if you want to show all column results with this, you need an addition comma `,` as well...

Comment: Hi, I actually mistyped Category as Character, but at times I keep getting this error even though I got the name right, other times it is correct, could this be attributable to the discrepancy in the environment?

Comment: Try `data1[which(data1$Category == "incidents_85_99"), ]`